# Path cost depending on edge directions

Tags: r, igraph

Let's assume a simple graph:

[1] -(3)-> [3] <-(2)- [2]

```
> library(igraph)
> df0 <- data.frame(i=c(1,2),j=c(3,3),w=c(3,2))
> g0 <- graph.data.frame(df0, directed=TRUE)
```

Now I want to calculate the cost travelling from [1] to [2] and from [2] to [1].

```
> E(g0, path=c(2,3,1), directed=FALSE)$w
[1] 2 3
> E(g0, path=c(1,3,2), directed=FALSE)$w
[1] 3 2
```

But I want the edge directions to play a role. An edge in direction of path would mean positive costs and an edge in opposite direction negative costs.

In my example travelling

- from [1] to [2] would cost 3*(+1) + 2*(-1) = 1
- and from [2] to [1] would cost 2*(+1) + 3*(-1) = -1

Is there a simple way or any way at all to calculate a binary vector which indicates the edge directions for a path from node A to node B?

**On a side note:**

A possible solution would be to simply add two directed edges with weights w and -w per link. Still it would be useful at times to simply determine the direction in a straight forward and computationally not overly expensive way.

Answer (score 0):

I'd be interested to see if there is a better way of doing this, but here is what I came up with.

```
cost132<-ifelse(get.edge.ids(g0,c(1,3, 3,2),directed=T)>0,1,-1)
sum(cost132 * E(g0, path=c(1,3,2), directed=FALSE)$w)
[1] 1

# for the opposite path, switch the coordinate pairs in the get.edge.ids functions
cost231<-ifelse(get.edge.ids(g0,c(2,3, 3,1),directed=T)>0,1,-1)
sum(cost231 * E(g0, path=c(2,3,1), directed=FALSE)$w)
[1] -1
```

It seems to me that given a path, one should be able to find out the directions associated with each edge along the path, but I couldn't find a simple way to do that.